# Ubuntu 16.10: source based routing: packets are not redirected

Tags: networking, router, policy

I'm trying to configure source based routing on my ubuntu-machine.
As simplest example I'm trying to configure the only one interface on my machine.
All configuration taken from here: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System

ip route

```
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
```

ip route show table rtgate

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
```

ip rule

```
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all to 10.0.2.15 lookup rtgate
32765:  from 10.0.2.15 lookup rtgate
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

But when I'm trying to pig 8.8.8.8 I always get 'Network is unreachable' message:
ping 8.8.8.8

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

ping -I enp0s3 8.8.8.8

```
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
```

I also tried to add fake/not-existed (10.0.2.16) gateway into global, but I got 'Destination Host Unreachable' messages.
It seems like the packets from 10.0.2.15 are not forwarded to 10.0.2.2 and packets just forwarded to default gateway.
`ip route flush cache` does not help.
Does anyone have any idea?

## Big update

### Ubuntu

This morning I continued my little investigation.
In beginning I reconfigured my ubuntu-machine: there was another interface added with default gateway.

```
root@metalmachine:~# ip route
default via 10.0.4.2 dev enp0s9
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
10.0.4.0/24 dev enp0s9  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.4.15
```

Target still the same: to configure source based routing for enp0s3.

```
root@metalmachine:~# ip route show table rtgate
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3

root@metalmachine:~# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from 10.0.2.15 lookup rtgate
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Yep. The same problem occurred.
When I'm running `ping -I enp0s3 8.8.8.8`, ICMP-responses successfully comes from 8.8.8.8 **BUT** they come through enp0s9. `tcpdump -i enp0s3 -n` still silent and when I'm shutting down enp0s9 responses stop coming.

### Debian

Ok, I was tried to configure same feature on Debian 8.7.

```
root@metalmachine:~# ip route
default via 10.0.3.2 dev eth1
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
10.0.3.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.15

root@metalmachine:~# ip route show table backup
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0

root@metalmachine:~# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from 10.0.2.15 lookup backup
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

That's what I got with running `tcpdump -i eth0 -n &`:

```
root@metalmachine:~# ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.2.15 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
11:36:34.432372 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 10.0.2.15, length 28
11:36:35.430668 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 10.0.2.15, length 28
^C

root@metalmachine:~# arp -an
? (10.0.2.2) at 52:54:00:12:35:02 [ether] on eth0
? (8.8.8.8) at <incomplete> on eth0
? (10.0.3.2) at 52:54:00:12:35:02 [ether] on eth1
```

Well, looks like system tries to resolve ARP for 8.8.8.8 and no matter what 8.8.8.8 located in different network. And no matter what proxy-arp is disabled on all interfaces:

```
root@metalmachine:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/proxy_arp
0
0
0
0
0
```

But when I tried `ping -I 10.0.2.15 8.8.8.8`:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.2.15 : 56(84) bytes of data.
11:54:58.434966 IP 10.0.2.15 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1430, seq 1, length 64
10:54:58.446248 IP 8.8.8.8 > 10.0.2.15: ICMP echo reply, id 1430, seq 1, length 64
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=11.4 ms
```

After watching counters of eth0 I was convinced that packets move through eth0. **IT WORKS!** But there are some conclusions:

1. Ubuntu 16.10 with iputils-s20150815 does not forward packets to specified routing table by `ip rule`s, or I'm doing it wrong. `ping -I enp0s3 8.8.8.8` sends packets through default route.
2. `ping` utility from iputils-s20150815 on Ubuntu 16.10 has some problems with `-I` argument or I'm doing it wrong. For example: `ping -I 10.0.2.15 8.8.8.8` returns `ping: unknown iface 10.0.2.15`
3. ping utility from iputils-s20121221 on Debian 8.7 tries to resolve ARP for host from different network or **I'm doing  it wrong**.

Please, could someone tell me where I'm wrong?